CiviCRM Wordpress Installation in C Panel
I am about to try installing CiviCRM in C-Panel web hosting. For other Wp sites I haved installed wordpress in the Public_HTML directory  e.g. public_HTML/wp-content/plugins etc
However the Civi installation guide https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/wordpress/ appears to use /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm  as the directory for installing CiviCRM. Is there a reason for making a different Directory for the wordpress (and civiCRM) installation?

Pretty sure that line is just an example. It also clearly says

Copy or ftp the zip file to your WordPress installation's /wp-content/plugins directory

